# Having trouble searching and replacing in my JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have been looking at trying to get this to work for a number of days but I am stuck.

I have a json data structure with values in it that I want to update, essentially using my json as a database to store configuration values.  Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "Actions": [
    {
      "Number": 1012,
      "RollbackPoint": "xxx_1012_RollbackPoint_xxx",
      "Parameters": [
        {
          "Name": "accountType",
          "Value": "xxx_1012_accountType_xxx"
        },
        {
          "Name": "userPassword",
          "Value": "xxx_1012_userPassword_xxx"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Number": 1015,
      "RollbackPoint": "xxx_1015_RollbackPoint_xxx",
      "Parameters": [
        {
          "Name": "accountType",
          "Value": "xxx_1015_accountType_xxx"
        },
        {
          "Name": "skipExport",
          "Value": "xxx_1015_skipExport_xxx"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to perform two updates

1. Update RollbackPoint to "1012" where Number = 1015
2. Update value to "AWS" where name = "accountType" under Parameters, where Number = 1012

So far the closest I have got to is using this:

```
cat json.txt | jq  '.[] | map(. + {RollbackPoint:(if (."Number") == 1015 then "1015" else .RollbackPoint end)})'
```

But this strips off the Actions[] element so its no good for me, I don't know where to even start on update 2...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, over 5 hours on google and I am still nowhere near.

Many thanks
Matt

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of the `//` operator to mimic (IMHO) nicer if-else trees in conjunction with various filtering filters.  Makes it rather easy to follow, compared to a large if-else tree.

```
.Actions |= map(
    (select(.Number == 1015) |
        .RollbackPoint = "1012"
    ) //
    (select(.Number == 1012) |
        .Parameters |= map((select(.Name == "accountType") | .Value = "AWS") // .)
    ) //
    .
)
```

Comment: Perfect!

Thank you so much Jeff that works like a charm.  I can see me using this all over the place now.

Kind regards
Matt

Comment: @msmithwr Glad you found your solution. Please mark Jeff's answer as accepted, to help other users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another jq solution

```
 .Actions[] |= (
      if .Number == 1015 then .RollbackPoint = "1012" else . end
    | if .Number == 1012 then .Parameters[] |= (
         if .Name == "accountType" then .Value = "AWS" else . end
      ) else . end
 )
```